# Regex in Google Sheets to extract outline values

Tags: google-sheets, re2

Want to extract outline values in a google sheet, using a formula

Tried Regex that will work with
Arrayformula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(RANGE,"REGEX")))

almost there but I'm thinking someone has the solution or an easier way to do this?

```
1(a) Background
1(a)(i) Historical context
1(a)(i)(A) Early influences
1(a)(i)(A)(1) Roman civilization
IIIV.
AA. Background
1.1 Historical context
34 Historical context
a. Early influences
i. Roman civilization
- Background
- Historical context
We are
I. Roman civilization
II. Romans
IV. 
IV. I am sad
iii
```

Expected output

```
1(a)
1(a)(i)
1(a)(i)(A)
1(a)(i)(A)(1)
IIIV.
AA.
1.1
34
a.
i.
-
-

I.
II.
IV.
IV.
iii
```

This seems to work but everything gets split over multiple columns, Removing some of the parenthesis from capture groups to prevent split resulted in not extracting "-"

```
Arrayformula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(RANGE,"REGEX")))
```

Regex:

```
^(([A-Za-z]|\d+)((\([A-Za-z\d]+\))|(\.\d+))*\.?|\-)\s+([^\n]+)
```

Possible solutions?

1. concatenating the output `Arrayformula([working CONCATENATE formula for variable columns](IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(RANGE,"REGEX")))`
2. I think the capture groups are needed for the regex to work, if thats true and if the output with google sheets by default uses a split() any ()into a new column, then perhaps using a substitute to replace any "(" or ")" with `~` prior to the `regexextract` and then after extracting these values

Then I was thinking to just use something like `Regexreplace(Range," .+","")` but this would extract out the first word of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you test:*

```js
=arrayformula(ifna(regexextract(A:A&"","^.*?[^a-zA-Z](?: |$)"),ifna(regexextract(A:A&"","^[a-z]*(?: |$)"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doubtless there's a pure regex approach to your problem, but (assuming I'm understanding your question properly), I think you could just use `choosecols` to get the last column of the `regexextract` 2D array:

```
=arrayformula(choosecols(iferror(regexextract(RANGE,"^(([A-Za-z]|\d+)((\([A-Za-z\d]+\))|(\.\d+))*\.?|\-)\s+([^\n]+)")),-1))
```

Comment: im going to update question. this doesnt seem to work it ends up extracting words but not "we" in case

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A14,"(?:^| )([\w ]+$)"))
```

[image]

### Explanation

`(?:^| )` - match the beginning of the string or a space without capturing it

`([\w ]+$)` - match and capture a word character `\w` (equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) or a space one or more times from the end `$` of the string